# python's readline module not available for windows?

Tags: import, python-import, readline, python-3.7

Granted I've been off PYTHON for two + years. I'm trying to get back into the swing, and I remember having command and variable completion available on windows a few years back. We were stuck in 2.6 as we had dependencies.

Today, I'm trying to import readline. I get this message from pip.

> > > C:\Users\Joe>pip3 install readline
> > >       Collecting readline
> > >         Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/01/2cf081af8d880b44939a5f1b446551a7f8d59eae414277fd0c303757ff1b/readline-6.2.4.1.tar.gz
> > >           Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:**error: this module is not meant to work on Windows**

my version is:

> > > Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> > >       Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> > >       import readline
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readline'

Answer (score 43):

I have recently faced the same issue on Windows 10. [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html) is not available for Windows, however there is [`pyreadline3`](https://github.com/pyreadline3/pyreadline3) (a continuation of the abandoned [`pyreadline`](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline) package) which is for windows and you may try it.

#### Try to install `pyreadline3` and use it instead of `readline`:

- pip: `pip install pyreadline3` or `python -m pip install pyreadline`
- [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba): `mamba install -c conda-forge pyreadline3`
- [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/): `conda install -c conda-forge pyreadline3`

Then, in your python file do this:

```
from pyreadline3 import Readline
readline = Readline()
```

That way, you can use `readline` in Windows like in linux systems.

Comment: I have not been able to make this work with cmd2. I use cygwin and pycharm. Is there anything I should be checking?

Comment: No error, that I can see, I just don't see the prompt (I do with cmd on windows and cmd2 on linux) and <tab> <tab> doesn't autocomplete, and it works on linux.

Comment: @Lefteris Xris  you are lifesaver! Confirming it works like a charm on Windows 10 cmd.exe python 3.8.3. I do not even need the two mentioned lines `from pyreadline 
import Readline;
readline = Readline()`

Comment: The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  pyreadline3        conda-forge/win-64::pyreadline3-3.4.1-py39hcbf5309_2 None
  python_abi         conda-forge/win-64::python_abi-3.9-2_cp39 None


Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: c:\QGB\Anaconda3



Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyreadline3'`

Comment: I did exactly this on Windows 10. But then `>>> "readline.get_current_history_length()"` returns `0`. And `>>>readline.write_history_file('C:\\folder1\\history1.txt')` creates that file, but it's empty! Why is there no history? I was hoping it would export the command history (I guess that's what it does), there was plenty.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your **CMD** terminal and type

> **pip install pyreadline**

with in few seconds it will be installed and you will be able to see message i.e. "Successfully installed pyreadline-"

then go back to your **PYSPARK** terminal and type again **import readline**
it will import now without any error

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I tried pyreadline after finding this question and had problems and eventually found that it is no longer supported.

What worked for me was installing pyreadline3 with:

```
pip install pyreadline3
```